# invalid cast from char* to int*

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

I am trying to use a buffer of `char` on the stack as storage for some other type of data.

As test I started with the most basic `int` but casting pointer of chars to pointer of integer doesn't compile.

```
 char buf[256]; 
 int* l = static_cast<int*>(buf);
 *l = 20;
```

The error I got is

```
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘char*’ to type ‘int*’
```

Being these primitive data I was expecting this to work: do you know what is the mechanics behind this specific case?

I sorted out by using `reinterpet_cast` but I'd like to use `static_cast` as this last should be more fast.

Comment: Why do you think static_cast is faster than reinterpret_cast for pointers?

Comment: `int l = static_cast<int>('c');` will work, but not for pointers

Comment: You shouldn't cast pointers like this unless you know what you are doing. The buffer might not be the right alignment for the int, in which case depending on your system, could crash or could work, but misaligned access tends to be very expensive in the CPU. So worrying about speed of casts is the least of your concerns.

Comment: `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` both do not cause any runtime slowdown. Probably you are mistaking it for `dynamic_cast`

Comment: @Predelnik Are you sure? `static_cast` is not always at compile-time.

Comment: @NeilKirk well yes, looks like it's not entirely correct, technically `static_cast` may call a conversion operator or constructor which may take arbitrary time.

Comment: @Predelnik Or convert float to int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a reinterpret cast. Here's how it works with proper alignment:

```
#include <memory>

std::aligned_storage<20 * sizeof(int), alignof(int)>::type storage;

int * p = reinterpret_cast<int *>(&storage);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != 20; ++i)
{
    ::new (p + i) int(i);    // or "p[i] = i;"
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for `::new`?

Comment: @NeilKirk: It's general.

Comment: Actually, if you use an array for storage and continue using placement-new, you don't need any casts, as in [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) (because placement-new takes a void pointer, and any object pointer can be implicitly converted to a void pointer).

Comment: Do you not need to call the destructors to be general?

Comment: @NeilKirk: Yes. You can omit destructors if the type is trivially destructible, and you can omit constructrors if it is trivially constructible.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: thanks for your respoonse now I do understand alignement requirements for storage a little bit more. What is the differece with the case where we get memory via 'malloc' ? Let's say I call malloc(20 * sizeof(int)) and that returns a 'void*' that I would normally cast  using C-style (int*): is the memory returned my 'malloc' correctly aligned? If not what can we do to fix this issue?

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile: The difference is twofold. `malloc` always returns memory suitably aligned for the platform's maximal alignment (i.e. `alignof(std::max_align_t`). With `std::aligned_storage`, you can request both smaller and larger alignments (though as always support for over-aligned types is implementation-defined).

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Thanks a lot for helping in this connection! Looks like new C++11 has really lot of good things to offer. Cheers!

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile: Yes. Alignment has never been part of the language until C++11; now the existence of alignment is acknowledged by the language, and it is controllable.